# RTX3060 cannot run Pytorch Yolov4 with cuda11.4

Tags: ubuntu, pytorch, darknet

Before I am using RTX2070 SUPER to run Pytorch Yolov4 and now my PC is changed to use RTX3060, ASUS KO GeForce RTX™ 3060 OC.

I have deleted the existing cuda11.2 and install again with cuda11.4 and Nvidia Driver 470.57.02

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.57.02    Driver Version: 470.57.02    CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:07:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   42C    P8    16W / 170W |    403MiB / 12053MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1236      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  9MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1264      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                6MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2124      C   python                            153MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However with the cuda11.4 and RTX3060, I cannot run Pytorch Yolov4 detection. When I run the detection, the detection will be stuck after loading weights, `Loading weights from ./data/people.weights... Done!`. In the meantime, nvidia-smi can show that a "python" (above PID 2124) is using the GPU memory and the used GPU memory of "python" will keep increasing.

**Is cuda11.4 not support RTX3060 or Pytorch1.4 yet?**

```
Environment:

ASUS KO GeForce RTX™ 3060 OC
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

cuda 11.4
nvidia driver 470.57.02
conda 4.8.3
python 3.8.5
pytorch 1.4
```

Comment: How did you install PyTorch?

Comment: hi @Berriel, sorry for my late reply. I have solved it by reinstalling the pytorch in the Conda env. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by reinstalling the pytorch in my Conda Env.

You may try reinstalling the Pytorch or create a new Conda Environment to do it again.